# Send an XSD message with WCF 4.0

Tags: wcf, xsd

I want to send the a schema from a WCF Service to the WCF Client. What are my best options? Can I send it using a simple string? Or I should send it as a file?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be enabling Metadata Exchange endpoint which will publish WSDL.
That WSDL will be automatically updated by .NET to provide latest version if you change code.

You can use configuration below to do that.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Server.CounterService">
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsDefault"
          contract="IMyContract">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```